# Implementing general back-propagation

Tags: python, numpy, neural-network, backpropagation

I'm trying to implement a back-propagation method for a fully connected layer with arbitrary activation function. I understand the general idea and math behind the algorithm but and i'm having difficulties with understanding the vectorized form...

I need help understanding the expected dimensions of the element

**known sizes:**

- Input - self.X is size (N,128)
- Weights - self.W is size (128,10)
- Biases - self.b is size (128,10)
- Output - self.y is size (N,10)
- Linear output (before activation) - self.z is size (N,10)

**unknown sizes:**
for **N=1** (Number of examples)

- dy - The gradient of the next layer - what size should it be?
- dz - The derivative of the activation function - what size should it be?
- self.d - The gradient of current layer - what size should it be?

Here is my code:

```
def backward(self, dy):
    if self.activator == 'relu':
        dz = np.zeros((self.z.shape[0], self.z.shape[1]))
        dz[self.z>0] = 1
    elif self.activator == 'sigmoid':
        dz = self.z * (1 - self.z)
    elif self.activator == 'soft-max':
        s = self.z.reshape(-1, 1)
        dz = np.diagflat(s) - np.dot(s, s.T)
    elif self.activator == 'none':
        dz = 1

    self.d = np.dot((dz * dy), self.W.T) # the error of the layer
    self.W_grad = np.dot(self.X.T, dy) # The weight gradient of the layer
    self.b_grad = np.sum(dy, axis=0).reshape(1, -1) # The bias gradient of the layer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple errors:

- `self.b` should have size  `self.b is size (10, )` not `(128, 10)` (as bias is per-unit, not per-unit-pair).
- `self.W_grad` should be `np.dot(self.X.T, (dz * dy))`, not `np.dot(self.X.T, dy)`.  Same for `self.b_grad` - it should be `np.sum(dz * dy, axis=0)`

As for the rest

`dy := dL/dy` should be `(N, 10)`, as it contains the gradient of the loss with respect to each element in y.

`dz := df(z)/d(z)` should be `(N, 10)` for an elementwise activation function, since `dz[i]` contains `df(z[i])/dz[i]`.

`self.d := dL/dX` should be `(N, 128)` because it contains the gradient of the loss with respect to each element in X.

Answer (score 1):

I believe, there is a slight confusion in your code: you write that `self.z` is the linear output *before* activation, but for some reason use that to compute activation derivative that you call `dz`. It should use the activation value instead. Then, assuming that you computed that value (I call it `prime` not to mix with my other `dz`), try this:

```
dz = dy * prime
dW = np.dot(dz, self.z.T)
db = np.sum(dz, axis=1, keepdims=True)
d = np.dot(self.W.T, dz)
```

Comment: You are right about the mistake in my code, but shouldn't the second row you wrote be: `dW = np.dot(dz, self.X.T)`? The derivative of the linear output is the input

Comment: Why is that wrong?  what he calls dz is `f'(z)` (which you call `prime`)

Comment: @Mark.F Regarding the order in `dW`: it solely depends on the forward pass. I usually multiply it to the left like this: `self.W * ...`. You can flip it if you multiply to the right.